# Append and fill row dataframe to a larger dataframe to create new columns

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a larger dataframe as follows:

```
df1

Month      Bkt    Cion
2021-06-01 Ofk    0.07
2021-06-01 Ofk    0.23
2021-06-01 Onk    0.10
2021-06-01 Onk    0.00
```

I have another very large single row dataframe as:

```
row.to_frame().T
        S1   S2
1       13   65
```

I want to append `row` to `df1` to get the following:

```
Month      Bkt    Cion   S1   S2
2021-06-01 Ofk    0.07   13   65
2021-06-01 Ofk    0.23   13   65
2021-06-01 Onk    0.10   13   65
2021-06-01 Onk    0.00   13   65
```

I am not sure how to approach the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to scale `df2` with [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html#pandas-index-repeat) + [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) to the same length as `df1`:

```
df1[df2.columns] = df2.loc[df2.index.repeat(len(df1))].values
```

`df1`:

```
        Month  Bkt  Cion  S1  S2
0  2021-06-01  Ofk  0.07  13  65
1  2021-06-01  Ofk  0.23  13  65
2  2021-06-01  Onk  0.10  13  65
3  2021-06-01  Onk  0.00  13  65
```

---

Another option with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat) + [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html#pandas-dataframe-ffill) on the `df2` columns:

```
new_df = pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1)
new_df[df2.columns] = new_df[df2.columns].ffill()
```

`new_df`:

```
        Month  Bkt  Cion    S1    S2
0  2021-06-01  Ofk  0.07  13.0  65.0
1  2021-06-01  Ofk  0.23  13.0  65.0
2  2021-06-01  Onk  0.10  13.0  65.0
3  2021-06-01  Onk  0.00  13.0  65.0
```

---

Frames Used:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Month': ['2021-06-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-06-01'],
    'Bkt': ['Ofk', 'Ofk', 'Onk', 'Onk'],
    'Cion': [0.07, 0.23, 0.1, 0.0]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'S1': [13], 'S2': [65]})
```